# Makefile: match multiple pattern rules

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile like this:

```
EXT = .cc
BLD = .build

all: bin/analyses/test

bin/analyses/test: $(BLD)/object.o

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(DEPS): $(BLD)/%.d: src/%$(EXT) | $(BLD)/$$(dir %)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MT '$(@:.d=.o)' $< -MF $@

$(BLD)/%.o: | $(BLD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(filter %$(EXT),$^) -o $@

bin/%: $(BLD)/%.o | $$(dir bin/%)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(filter %.o,$^) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

bin/%/ $(BLD)/%/:
    mkdir -p $@
```

If line 6 looks the way it is, then everything works. Both `bin/analyses/test:` and `bin/%:` rules are used. But if I change line 6 to

```
bin/analyses/%: $(BLD)/object.o
```

only the `bin/%:` rule gets picked up.

How can I make multiple pattern rules match for the same target?

Comment: What's `EXES`? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: @user657267 I've edited the question.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you intend. Which object file(s) do you want to link to build the executable?

Comment: `bin/analyses/test` would be made from `.build/analyses/test.o` and `.build/object.o`.

Comment: And you want `.build/object.o` to be a prerequisite of every file in `.build/analyses/`?

Comment: @Beta yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Make sometimes removes trailing slashes from targets, which can cause some confusion. In this case it takes your rule `bin/%/ $(BLD)/%/: ...`, which you clearly intended for directories, and uses it for   files, at least sometimes. It is easy enough to do without an explicit rule for directories, by using `mkdir -p` in other rules.

Second, Make doesn't combine pattern rules the way it does ordinary rules. It finds one pattern rule and uses that. In a relatively simple case like this, we can write a rule that will do what we want:

```
all: bin/analyses/test

$(BLD)/%.o:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

bin/analyses/%: $(BLD)/analyses/%.o $(BLD)/object.o
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

bin/%: $(BLD)/%.o
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

(There is some obvious redundancy in those last two rules which I don't see how to iron out without making the makefile less readable, but it works as intended.)